# Additional mask files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, extract-by-mask

I used the tool "Extract by Mask" to clip a raster. It resulted in 5 tif images: mask, maskc1, maskc2, maskc3, and maskc4. What are the maskc1-4 files? They're large and I'd like to delete them if they won't effect my normal mask tif. I'm trying to preview them in ArcCatalog but it's taking forever to build pyramids.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever wondering the same thing, I deleted them and there were no issues.